# Get the current Url of web browser in C#

Tags: c#

How can i get the current url (the opened url in web browser) in a text box ?

for example:

webBrowser1.Url= new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");

and my browser opened the link !!

Now I want to get the url (http://stackoverflow.com) in a text box

regards.

Answer (score 7):

```
yourTextBox.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
```

Comment: yes ! its good but you have to wait until the web browser load the url or you will get an error ... thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
Result : http://localhost:1302/TESTERS/Default6.aspx
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;

result : /TESTERS/Default6.aspx
string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;


result : localhost
string host = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host;
```